# Debezium - Postgres-connector receiving snapshots but not streaming changes after snapshot done?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I have followed Debezium tutorial on https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.6/tutorial.html and https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.6/connectors/postgresql.html#postgresql-publication-autocreate-mode, with Databases using PostgreSQL and all services set up using Docker Desktop on WSL

Debezium succesfully getting all the snapshots from the provided table. But when it tried to consume the changes event, it not receiving anything. What do you think happens?

What i have tried:

1. Run script to automatically update the database
2. Register postgres connectors (tested using curl against `localhost:8083/connectors/debezium-pgconnector/status` shown that it is RUNNING).
3. Using kafka's Kafka-console-consumer.sh provided with kafka, with `--from-beginning` tag provided . It shown that it successfully snapshot all row of the provided tables.
4. Running the kafka-console-consumer.sh without from-beginning tag (not getting any changes)

Here's my connector configuration

```
{
    "name": "debezium-pgconnector",  
    "config": {
      "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector", 
      "tasks.max": "1",
      "plugin.name": "pgoutput", 
      "database.hostname": "172.19.211.117", 
      "database.port": "5432", 
      "database.user": "debezium", 
      "database.password": "12345678", 
      "database.dbname" : "database1", 
      "schema.include.list": "public", 
      "table.include.list": "public.users", 
      "topic.prefix": "db1", 
      "publication.autocreate.mode": "filtered",
      "heartbeat.interval.ms": "5",
      "heartbeat.action​.query" :"INSERT INTO public.debezium_heartbeat (id, ts) VALUES (1, NOW()) ON CONFLICT(id) DO UPDATE SET ts=EXCLUDED.ts;"
    }
  }
```

any lines that potentially shown error is only this one

```
connect   | 2023-07-25 07:36:58,731 WARN   ||  [Producer clientId=connector-producer-debezium-pgconnector-0] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 4263 : {__debezium-heartbeat.db1=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}   [org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient]
kafka     | 2023-07-25 07:36:58,763 - INFO  [data-plane-kafka-request-handler-4:Logging@66] - [ReplicaFetcherManager on broker 1] Removed fetcher for partitions Set(__debezium-heartbeat.db1-0)
```